# Have a customized progress bar in HTML on click of a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am a novice HTML coder and have a silly issue!
I want to have a customized progress bar that shows the progress once SUBMIT is clicked. I tried using the  tag of HTML, but it did not do the job for me.
How can I have an animation like this integrated with my code: http://www.jqueryscript.net/chart-graph/Customizable-Liquid-Bubble-Chart-With-jQuery-Canvas.html#viewSource

I am not able to figure out in what section what code has to be put.

I have tried this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#myProgress {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

#label {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">
    <div id="label">10%</div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button> 

<script>
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 10;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
      document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This doesn't work because I dont want the progress bar to be visible before I click submit.

Comment: That would require you to submit your form through AJAX.

Comment: @Julie Could you please direct me to a link that tells me how to do that?

Comment: Search Google for `jquery form submit ajax tutorial` and you'll get plenty of results.

Comment: @RowenaRavenclaw Please mark one of answer to finishing this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

in #myBar Css Property

```
Display:none
```

is Used and in Function Again This Property is Changed to Display:inline by

```
elem.style.display = "inline";
```

Here is The Modified Code.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <style>
    #myProgress {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      background-color: #ddd;
    }

    #myBar {
      position: absolute;
      width: 10%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      display:none; /*Displays None */

    }

    #label {
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 30px;
      color: white;
    }
    </style>
    <body>

    <h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

    <div id="myProgress">
      <div id="myBar">
        <div id="label"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <button onclick="move()">Click Me</button> 

    <script>
    function move() {


      var elem = document.getElementById("myBar"); 
      var label=document.getElementById("label");
      var width = 10;
      var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
      function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {

          clearInterval(id);
        } else {
          width++; 
          elem.style.display = "inline"; //Sets Display property to its default value.   
          elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
          label.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';

        }
      }
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can Add: Onclick="move()" in Submit Button

Comment: I did that (Onclick="move()").. But the function is not getting called. (To verify if the function is getting called, I used an alert at the beginning of the function!)

Comment: @RowenaRavenclaw In _Browser_ while testing your code Press **F12**. If You see an error there , Solve it or post here to be solved!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code if you have `jquery 1.8`. In this version of jquery you can get progress of animation using `progress` property. So you can use `animate()` instead of `setInterval()` to do this work. See example

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    var width = $(".progress").children("div").width();
    if (width == 0){
        var percent = $(".progress").data("percent");
        $(".progress").children("div").width("0%").show().animate({
            "width": percent + "%"
        }, {
            duration: 2000,
            progress: function(a, p) {
                var newPer = Math.round(percent * p);
                $(".progress").children("div").html(newPer + "%"); 
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.progress {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.progress > div {
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #1C90F3;
    color: #fff;    
    display: none;
    font-family: tahoma;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress" data-percent="80">
    <div></div>
</div>
<br/>
<button>Animate progress</button>
```

Comment: I want the actual progress to be seen. How could I do that?